# Integration of differential forms

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

I have just started to learn differential forms. Now, there is a concept of pulling integral back. I somewhat understood the procedure to do it. But, I don't understand why we do it and when to use the trick?

Comment: Can you edit your answer to provide a bit of detail as to what you know and where exactly you are stuck? At present, it's going to be quite hard to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same concept by which we change variables for an integral.

Comment: If it is just change of variable why text books devote full section/chapter on it?

Comment: If it is "just" a change of variable maybe not. But it has got many not obvious properties that one need to know, and it is a general concept, so one has to pay the right amount of time on it.